# How much is to much PERM in Java (1.5GB seems high)

Tags: java, jvm

We run a large java based application that is under heavy development.  Every 3 to 6 months it seems we have to increase the size of the PERM memory or we risk running out of memory either when the application starts or shortly after coming online.  The application is hosted in JBoss 4.2 and tomcat servers.

Our current setting are:

**-server -Xms12G -Xmx12G -XX:MaxPermSize=1536M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode**

I can help but wonder if this seems awful high.

The PERM memory seems to fill up very quickly on startup.  anywhere between 90 to 99% using jstat.

Our web application consists of 30 plus individual war files.  In JBoss these are deployed as one large 300MB+ ear file.

Is it normal for a large application to us this much PERM?

Comment: Maybe it is time to break up the app ? What is in this 300MB EAR file ? You must have a bunch of graphics and other contents, maybe you could move your static contents to being served by the web server and let the AppServer do the logic.

Comment: This seems really, really, really, really high. Don't have anything really useful to suggest, but how big is your codebase? And is it possible you're loading multiple copies of libraries under different classloaders? Not too familiar with the current JBoss Classloader except that there've been issues reported, do you get similar results on another container?

Comment: The code base is quite large (ERP system).  100+ external jar libraries (some are customer some are off the shelf) that are "shared" in the EAR file (common lib) but from my reading it would seem the each war would get its own copy.  Is that true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is hella lot of permgen space. If it fills up right away, that implies an almost inconceivable number of classes. Is there a lot of duplication in libraries across those 30 war files? You could save a lot of space by loading common libraries from a common classloader closer to the root, rather than in each separare webapp. Try installing common libraries in the server directories.

Comment: interned Strings take permgen space, I would use a profiler to determine what is using so much memory. And if there are duplicates.

Comment: As far as I know all the common jars are in the lib directory of the EAR or a common lib directory on tomcat.  Per my comment above and some reading it seems like each war will load it's own copy of the lib file but still trying to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Is 1.5 GB overhead to manage a 12 GB heap as well as class code / static data really so outrageous?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that there may be a memory leak in your application? Try using a profiler tool like the JProfiler or the [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to analyze the memory usage of your application. I have seen that simple memory leaks can cause huge disruptions over a period of time.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to get some additional opinions before I went back to the team.  Seems the Internet has confirmed my assumption.